Qt 6 C++, App Icon Missing when Right-Clicking in Taskbar
I have added the icon of the app in the main.cpp as follows:
MainWindow w;  w.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/images/logo.png"));
The icon can show up in the taskbar when app is running. But the icon is missing in the pop-up menu, when I right click on the app. The issue is shown in the the image: 
Adding this line in the mainwindow.cpp does not work either:
setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/images/logo.png"));
Anything that I am missing in the Qt 6 C++ code? Thanks.

As per https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/appicon.html, the icon of an exe file requires using a non-Qt, platform-dependent technique.

The non-Qt approach from this document works. Thanks.
